# SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml, parseexception

I'm trying to deploy an application on tomcat 7.0.23 (the web app is all compiled and built), and I've been getting this error in catalina.out:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/Library/Tomcat/webapps/app2/WEB-INF/lib/javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 5, 2012 10:28:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Library/Tomcat/webapps/app2/WEB-INF/lib/javaee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 5, 2012 10:28:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/app2/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:48)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1194)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1090)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1003)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1742)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5148)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:222)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Jan 5, 2012 10:28:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Jan 5, 2012 10:28:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jan 5, 2012 10:28:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/app2] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I can't find anything on this error by googling, please help.

Comment: Your web.xml file seems to be not valid. Could you post it somewhere(e.g. on pastebin.com) and give a link?

Comment: I know for sure this is a valid web.xml, because I had the app running just a while ago, and nothing changed. why does tomcat needs ziputils for an xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have duplicate jars in classpath due to which tomcat couldn't able to load java-ee.jar which ultimately led to web.xml parse error. Make sure you have only one java-ee.jar available in classpath.

Comment: Thank, it seems that this was the problem, I did have multiple java-ee.jar files in classpath, plus antoher javaee-6-api.jar